# All UNIQUE permutations

Tags: vba, excel, permutation

I'm finding lots of algorithms to get every permutation of digits in a set of numbers. What I can't find is one that gives a UNIQUE list of such permutations.

For example, the digits **123** will produce:

```
123
132
213
231
312
321
```

But the digits **113** should only produce (skipping the duplicates):

```
113
131
311
```

If it helps, I'll be using 8 digits in an array.

Thanks

Comment: Please fix your tags - is it VBA or VB6 that you are using?

Comment: Either. I can convert between the two easily.

Comment: But a VBA solution which makes use of Excel's "Remove Duplicates" feature **can't** be easily implemented in VB6 so "I can convert between the two easily" is dependent on the removal of the [excel-vba] tag at least.

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the data from cell a2 down and run the macro.

```
Sub UniqueNumber()
    Dim vDB, vR(), a
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, n As Long, z As Integer
    Dim k As Integer, p As Integer
    Dim dic As Object
    Dim s As String

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    vDB = Range("a2", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(3))
    z = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 3)
    For i = 1 To z: For j = 1 To z: For k = 1 To z

        If i <> j And i <> k And j <> k Then
            vR(1) = vDB(i, 1)
            vR(2) = vDB(j, 1)
            vR(3) = vDB(k, 1)
            s = Join(vR, "")
            If dic.Exists(s) Then
            Else
                n = n + 1
                dic.Add s, s
            End If
        End If
    Next k: Next j: Next i
    a = dic.Keys
    Range("d2").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Clear
    Range("d2").Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(a)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Works great. I haven't worked with dictionary/keys before and will have look closer on what it does. Thanks.

Comment: OK, not the best way to get the permutations if you're dealing with larger strings, but I can apply the dictionary method to another permutations algorithm to get what I want.